# Populate a combobox with vector layer name in QGIS 3.X plugin

Tags: qgis-plugins, update, python-3, combo-box

I'm updating a QGIS 2.14 Python code plugin to QGIS 3.X.

I'm stuck in the attribution of vector name in combobox.
The problem is that I don't have any error message but the combobox aren't filled at all. I don't know how to progress since there is no error message.

[image]

Can someone spot the error or give me advice to pass 2.14 code to 3.X?

I'm using Python Builder

Comment: Please do not provide a picture of code.  Instead, provide the actual code in the body of the question, so that those who would help you don't need to retype all your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace `layer1.type() == QgsVectorLayer()` by `layer1.type() == 0`

You can execute the following code in the Python console in order to try and check the result expected :

```
my_comb = QComboBox()
my_comb.clear()

layers = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().layerOrder()
layer_list = []

for layer1 in layers:
    if layer1.type() == 0: # 0 if it is a vector layer
        layer_list.append(layer1.name())

print(layer_list) # your list

my_comb.addItems(layer_list)
my_comb.show()
```

I'll let you adjust the code.

Comment: it work perfectly find thx